# How to perform reserved checkout (file locking) in CVS

Tags: cvs, file-locking

I want to perform a reserved checkout on a particular file in CVS so I can be the only one to edit the file. I tried the command `cvs admin -l <filename>` but i'm getting an error as below:

cvs [server aborted]: user is restricted to repository administrator.

It seems that I'm not an admin in the CVS server but I don't know how to check it. Where should I need to check it? We don't have an administrator resource for CVS so I don't know where can I ask help. Btw, I executed the foregoing command in command line (cmd) since i dont know how can i enter in unix from CVS.

Also, is there other way (aside from `cvs admin -l` command) to checkout file in CVS where there will be no other resource who can edit the file except for the one checked out the file? I'm just asking if ever that I may not be able to have an admin access in CVS. I have read some articles that the cvs watch can do it but I was not able to understand it fully since I'm new in CVS.

Comment: What is the "wc" command you refer to?

Comment: sorry, it's a typo error.it should be 'cvs admin -l' rather

Comment: You can edit your question so no one else is confused.